# Compact Sets and Covers?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

I'm having a tough time trying to find an example of a cover of $[0,1]$ of a collection of intervals in the form $[a,b)$ which does NOT have a finite subcover. Any help?

Comment: Should your cover consist of open sets? If so, what is the topology?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\left\{\left[0,\frac12\right),\left[\frac12,\frac23\right),\left[\frac23,\frac34\right),\ldots\right\}\cup\bigl\{[1,2)\bigr\}$$will do. In fact, this cover has *no* subcover whatsoever other than itself.

Comment: @Bungo Sure. Thanks. I've edited my answer.

Comment: This covers $(0,1)$ (with no finite subcover), but it does not cover $[0,1]$ as it misses both endpoints.

Comment: @Bungo Again, thanks. What do you think now?

Comment: Looks good now! (+1)

Comment: Thank you so much! I couldn't figure out the [1,2) part for some reason :P I appreciate it!